# How do I exclude a role from accessing a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have a section in my application that part-time people are not allowed to use, but full-time employees are allowed. We have far more full-time employees than part-time; so I figured it would be easier to create a role that lists the part-timers and **exclude them from this controller** instead of getting a full list of full-timers and maintain that list. I haven't found anything that really fits what I am looking for. Most of the solutions seem to extend the functionality of Authorize, but I can't find something that is close to what I am looking for.

Can you point me in the right direction?

For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles!="PartTimers")]
public class MyController : Controller { }
```

Comment: It should be `[Authorize(Roles="FullTimers")]`, anything else goes against the grain of the fx here. What happens when a new group of users (Guests) is later defined?

Comment: This is a payroll application. All employees can work with their timesheets. Only full-time people can request vacation. I would prefer to exclude the few people that can't access this page then to maintain a list of people that can access the page.

Comment: Otherwise I'll just secure by obscurity. I'll remove the menu options and then they won't find the pages.

Comment: _I'll remove the menu options_ - that's no security at all.

Comment: And the effort for "maintaining a list" is not proportional to the number of members. You'll need a checkbox or something on the entry form anyway.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I realize removing the menu options isn't "secure". However, in this case, we aren't talking about seeing information they aren't allowed to, a part-time person just can't submit a vacation request. On top of that, I have in the code logic to prevent part-time from submitting a request anyway. I just want to remove this from view so they aren't confused thinking they need to submit a request to take an unpaid day off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `[Authorize(Roles="FullTimers")]`, anything else goes against the grain of the provided framework here.

What would happen when a new group of users (Guests) is later defined? It is much safer to explicitly grant them access then to scan the entire app for actions that need denial.

Th WebForms framework does provide a `<deny roles ="..." />` feature but it is mostly used with `roles="*"` and `users="?"` and that is not as applicable here.

> I figured it would be easier to create a role that lists the part-timers and exclude them from this controller instead of getting a full list of full-timers and maintain that list.

The effort for "maintaining a list" is not proportional to the number of members. You'll need a checkbox or something on the entry form anyway.